# 17.10: How to auto mount drives on startup?

Tags: mount, startup, 17.10

Every time I log in, I need to go to disks and mount all my partitions manually.

How can I make it automatic?

Comment: `/etc/fstab` [file system table] is a list file filesystems to mount, either automatically or on command.  it'll load hdds, network (nfs, samba & more) & more.  add entries to your existing file which will have at least one entry (your / drive to enable boot).  have the entries `auto` mount.  you didn't say what `disks` so I'll not go further .

Comment: add the output to your question; it allows formatting (unlike comments).   your example is UUID=61bb.. (uuid=[universal] unique id which is created on format for each drive, it gets mounted as /, type is `ext4`, options are "if errors, remount read-only", freq.count,  pass_no.  make an entry with new UUID,  location to mount drives, type-of-format etc.

Comment: follow Orian's answer if you like gui approach ... i'm a command guy so commands are faster & easier for me.  `man fstab` to get help on fstab, though most people probably use a duckduckgo.com (or other)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the "Disks" app.

Load the Disks app (In System) and select the disk with the filesystem you want to mount on startup.

Then select the filesystem on that disk and click on the gears (for configuration).

Select "Edit Mount Options" from the popup menu.

On the setup options, click to check the "Mount on Startup" box.
(This will add the entry to fstab when you click on "OK").

Reboot, and your filesystem should be available.

I agree with other comments here regarding manually adding lines to fstab via CLI/text editor. If you take the time to look at your fstab file it will help you understand what changes have been made and, ultimately the CLI method will become faster for you.

Comment: Program real name is `gnome-disk-utility` . I can't understand, why people identify programs by simple common words (like title name) in Linux/Ubuntu world, where all is configurable and replacable. Not every linux distribution has "Disks" in "Main menu".

Comment: The comment in question was specific to Ubuntu 17.10 as specified in the original post title; Therefore the common nomenclature of that particular release was utilized.

Answer (score 20):

1 - Write down the UUID of the drive that you want to mount by executing the following command:

```
sudo blkid
```

2 - Then edit the fstab:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

3 - Add at the end of the file fstab:

```
UUID=D638F77338F7514B /media/baraldi/win_www ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Be sure the UUID matches what you recorded in the first step

4 - Restart

That is all. Good Luck.

Comment: Important to note: this can restrict you from starting your system! Use with caution!

Comment: sudo nano /etc/fstab  don't launch gedit as sudo