# Plugin of X-plane can't read file on /media/

Tags: sasl

I have a X-Plane 11 flight-sim. It can handle plugins and third-party aircraft. One of this aircraft consists of special plugins, needed to verify that every gauge is working perfectly and it checks the activation of the aircraft.

This sim is located on `/dev/sda5`, but the file path looks like `/media/myuser/66A.../X-Plane 11`

When I try to load a plane I get this in log.txt.

```
[SASL ERROR] Can't load file /media/darktwister/66AD6CA2051FE7BF/X-Plane 11/Aircraft/763/aircraft.key
```

On Windows the same plane works like a charm. I've `chmod 777`'d everything, but still, the sim can't read the file from the path.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Any ideas how to make it work? Maybe the reason is the `/media/` path?

Comment: make a permanent mount point and try then. https://askubuntu.com/questions/966706/17-10-how-to-auto-mount-drives-on-startup did any other third-party planes (mods) work on ubuntu or is this the first one you are trying?

Comment: @tatsu

i am really retarded at mount points, could you explain it please ?) And i forgot to mention: /dev/sda5 is the NTFS system, mb this is the problem?

I tried a lot of mods, but only this requires a file from another directory.

Comment: can't you just copy the file to your documents or inside the game folder? where is the path to this file decided?

Comment: @tatsu, folder is super-ultra big(about 100gbs), its really hard to move, cause, when i marked free spaces for linux, i made a system /dev/ about 20gbs :(

Comment: oh I didn't anticipate that. ok we'll leave it there. making a permanenet mount point is easy. just open up "disks", select your drive, click on the gear icon (it's options) and select "Modify mounting options" then turn off default options, go to monting point and fill it in with something better like : "/media/BigDrive" or whatever, and then reboot.